# Bash script to replace this pattern in a file with another

Tags: bash, replace

I'm trying to create a bash script replace all occurrences of the

`<?= /* @noEscape */ __('any random string, of any length') ?>`

with

`<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('any random string, of any length')) ?>`

in a specific file or directory.

The issue is the inner string can be anything.

So far I've tried using `sed`.  Maybe this is not the best approach.

Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
sed 's/\/\* @noEscape \*\/ __\('.*'\)/$block->escapeHtml\('.*'\)\)/g' $1 > $1.test
mv $1.test $1
```

Comment: Does the "random string" ever contain single-quotes (`'`) or right-parentheses (`)`) or end tag (`?>`)? Does the end tag (`?>`) ever not appear on the same line as the opening tag? Do any lines ever contain more than one set of `<?= ... ?>` (even partial)?

Comment: @jhnc good points. Yes, this can sometimes be the case.  Maybe I should do it manually in this case, but it would also be nice to have to do it on a file by file basis and then I could double check.

Comment: You need a tool that can detect matching `<?=` / `?>`. You'd be better off using a tool that understands your template language rather than sed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, if you really want to replace the inner string by .*, I guess you want to replace it by the original string, right?

Then you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e"s|/\* @noEscape \*/ __(\('.*'\))|\$block->escapeHtml(\1)|g" $1 > $1.test
mv $1.test $1
```

If you really want to replace the inner string by .* (e.g. if you intend to generate a regex):

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e"s|/\* @noEscape \*/ __(\('.*'\))|\$block->escapeHtml('.*')|g" $1 > $1.test
mv $1.test $1
```

In both versions I used `'s|...'` the second char behind the `s` signals sed, what separator I want to use. I chose `|`, so I don't need to escape `/`.
If you want `$block`  to be replaced by the content of the shell variable `block` you just need to remove the `\` before `$block` above.

`(` in `sed` regex (without escaping) means the character `(`, while `\(` is the start of a capturing group, that ends with `\)`, so `(\('.*'\))` captures the string surounded by `('` and `')` and puts it in a capturing group. Because it is the first capturing group in the regex, you get its content in the replacement-string by `\1`.